# How do can I combine two columns to perform an aggregation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say I have a table with these columns:

| person | color | date1 | date2 | aux | car_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | green | 1/10/22 | null | 11 | suv |
| 1 | blue | null | 1/11/22 | 16 | sedan |
| 3 | red | 1/23/22 | null | 17 | suv |
| 3 | yellow | null | 1/28/22 | 26 | sedan |
| 4 | purple | 1/27/22 | null | 14 | suv |
| 4 | black | null | 1/21/22 | 17 | sedan |

I would like to obtain the earliest date a vehicle was bought, between a particular interval. If no vehicle was bought in that interval by a person, then that date will be null. If there are two vehicles bought in that interval by someone, the earliest one should be picked.

In other words, the following result set is the desired result if the interval is say, between 1/20/22 - 1/30/22 (inclusive):

| person | date | car type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 3 | 1/23/22 | suv |
| 4 | 1/21/22 | sedan |

The pattern I thought of using for this is:

```
SELECT person, date, car_type 
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY date ASC) AS rn, 
     person, 
     date, 
     car_type
    FROM car_table
) sub
WHERE sub.rn = 1;
```

But there are two date columns, and I'd like to know how I can combine them into one for this purpose; or if there is just a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Unvpivot your data first, and then get the "top 1 per group." Alternatively, if you're on SQL Server 2022, you have access to `LEAST`. Or (possibly best) normalise your design and don't have 2 date columns that represent the same thing.

Comment: Side note, your attempt isn't valid syntax. You have spelt `PARTITION` incorrectly, your derived table has no `FROM`, so `person`, `date` and `car_type` column have no context, and the function is `ROW_NUMBER`, not `ROW`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and sorry for the errors. Unfortunately i can't redesign the table and the data has to be dealt with as is. Unless you meant creating a cte and combining it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, assuming you are using the latest version of SQL Server (2022 at time of writing) you can use `LEAST` to get the lower value of the 2 date and time columns. `LEAST` ignores `NULL` values as well. It not clear if the logic for the dates should be based on if one of the dates should be between the dates or the lowest, so this may not give the required results for different data, but should give you enough to get there:

```sql
SELECT ID
INTO dbo.Person
FROM (VALUES(1),(3),(4))V(ID);

SELECT *
INTO dbo.BoughtVehicle
FROM (VALUES(1,'green','1/10/22',NULL,'11','suv'), --d/M/yy or M/d/yy are TERRIBLE date formats. Use a date and time data type!
            (1,'blue',NULL,'1/11/22','16','sedan'),
            (3,'red','1/23/22',NULL,'17','suv'),
            (3,'yellow',NULL,'1/28/22','26','sedan'),
            (4,'purple','1/27/22',NULL,'14','suv'),
            (4,'black',NULL,'1/21/22','17','sedan'))V(person,color,date1,date2,aux,car_type);
GO
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT person,
           LEAST(date1,date2) AS date,
           car_type,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY LEAST(date1,date2)) AS RN
    FROM dbo.BoughtVehicle
    WHERE (date1 >= '1/20/22' AND date1 <= '1/30/22')  --This uses ambiguous varchar literals, you should be using an unambiguous date format like yyyyMMdd against a date and time value
       OR (date2 >= '1/20/22' AND date2 <= '1/30/22'))
SELECT P.ID AS Person,
       RN.date,
       RN.car_type
FROM dbo.Person P
     LEFT JOIN RNs RN ON P.ID = RN.Person
                     AND RN.RN = 1;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.BoughtVehicle;
DROP TABLE dbo.Person;
```